# How can I convert strings like 2017-03-09T10:34:11Z to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, string-to-datetime

I am trying to analyze the Open Food Facts Dataset.
The Dataset is very messy!
I am currently trying to convert the 'created_datetime' object to a Python datetime object. The entries in this column all look like "2017-03-09T10:34:11Z".
I have tried the normal to_datetime method with and without "infer_datetime_format". Neither of them worked.
I then changed to format of the string to look like this "2017 03 09 10 34 12" (I deleted the "Z" and "T" and added a space between every number).
I then tried to run to_datetime again setting the format to '%Y %m %d %I M% %S'.
But no matter what I do, I get an error. In this case, I get: "'%' is a bad directive in format '%Y %m %d %I M% %S'".
Could someone please help me out?
I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Post some of the data or a link to the dataset so that others can help!

Comment: That string works with that format. If it's working on some of your strings but not others, the best guess is that it's because you used `%I` (12-hour clock hour) instead of `%H` (24-hour clock hour), but we'd need to see an actual example of it failing to do more than guess.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include some sample data and the code of what you tried before. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: But meanwhile, why are you changing the string? Why not just use a format that matches your string, like `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ`?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do ? If you want normal datetime, then why not use pandas.to_datetime method () ?

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
pd_date_time = pd.to_datetime("2017-03-09T10:34:11Z")
py_date_time = pd_date_time.to_pydatetime()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the "Z" and "T" such as in my example below you can use datetime.strptime to convert to datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime
messy_date = "2017-03-09 10:34:11"
messy_date = messy_date.replace('T',' ')
messy_date = messy_date.replace('Z',' ')
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(messy_date, '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
print(datetime_object)
```

Output is: *2017-03-09 10:34:11*

Comment: You don't have to remove the `Z` or `T` to use `strptime`; you can just put them in the format string.

Comment: I just tried that...  data['created_datetime'] = datetime.strptime(data['created_datetime'], '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
i get the following error :strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Comment: It is not working because you have to iterate through all values. Try this: data['created_datetime'] = data['created_datetime'].map(lambda a: datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%SZ')). Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what types of objects you have, so I don't know what the `to_datetime` function does.

But functions like `datetime.datetime.strptime` or anything from Pandas will work with exactly the example you gave. But they won't work with a slightly different example, like this:

```
2017 03 09 13 34 12
```

Why? Because you're using `%I`, which means 12-hour-clock hour, instead of `%H`, which means 24-hour-clock hour, and `13` isn't a valid value for `%I`.

But really, why change the string in the first place? Why not just use a format that matches your string as it is?

```
>>> s = '2017-03-09T10:34:12Z'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 9, 10, 34, 12)
```

Or, if you're using one of the Pandas functions, or something out of `dateutil`, they should just work by default:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime("2017-03-09T10:34:12Z")
Timestamp('2017-03-09 10:34:12')
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("2017-03-09T10:34:12Z")
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 9, 10, 34, 12, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

(Notice that `dateutil` even recognized the `Z` as meaning we explicitly want a UTC timestamp, rather than a naive timestamp.)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried regex? Or even simple `yr, mo, day, hr, min, sec = datetime.split(" ")` should work.